# None Type object while using Beautiful soup to extract text from a url

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I was trying to extrct the text from 3 urls given in code file (2 commented). I tried to extrct the text from those url and store onto a text file. While my code is working for most of the urls but it is giving error with few urls. I have given examples of 3 of them. I used Beautiful Soup.
The code file is

```
    import requests
    import io
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

    #url = 'https://foundersfund.com/our_team'
    #url = 'https://a16z.com/about/team'
    url = 'https://ctinnovations.com/learn-about-connecti...'


res = requests.get(url)
html_page = res.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page, 'html.parser')
soup.body.a.text
soup.body.p.b
text = soup.find_all(text=True)

tag = soup.find('div', id='I1_sys_txt')
print(tag.get_text() if tag else "<none found>")

output = ''
blacklist = [
    '[document]',
    'noscript',
    'header',
    'html',
    'meta',
    'head', 
    'input',
    'script',
    # there may be more elements you don't want, such as "style", etc.
]


for t in text:
    if t.parent.name not in blacklist:
        output += '{} '.format(t)
outFile = '<filepath>//<filename.txt>'        
with io.open(outFile,"w", encoding="utf-8") as textFile:
    textFile.write(output)
print(type(output))     
print(output)
#print('output'.join(soup.stripped_strings))
```

This gives me an error as folllows :

---

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-47bbd55e7171> in <module>
     10 html_page = res.content
     11 soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page, 'html.parser')
---> 12 soup.body.a.text
     13 soup.body.p.b
     14 text = soup.find_all(text=True)

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

I appreciate it if anyone cn wlk me through my mistake and get the correct code apllicable to all urls.

Thanks

Salil

Comment: Try with `id_` instead of `id` please

Comment: well the error pretty much says that directly there is no `a` tag after `body` tag

Comment: I would suggest checking the `soup` content first, if it's 404 then you does not have an `a` tag in `body`

Comment: Are you sure you have this `'div', id='I1_sys_txt'` in all your URLs?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone
I could solve the issue with the following set of codes

```
    # EXTRACTING THE URL TEXTS

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
import io


L = range(len(url_list))
for i in L:
    url = (url_list[i][0])
    sotretxt = (vcfrm_list[i][0])
    print (url)
    print (sotretxt)
    print ("---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
    hdr = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
    req = Request(url,headers=hdr)
    page = urlopen(req)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
    text = soup.find_all(text=True)
    output = ''
    
    blacklist = [
        '[document]',
        'noscript',
        'header',
        'html',
        'meta',
        'head', 
        'input',
        'script',
        # there may be more elements you don't want, such as "style", etc.
    ]
    for t in text:
        if t.parent.name not in blacklist: 
            output += '{} '.format(t)
            
    path= 'C://Users//ubana//OneDrive//ANIL JOSHI//PROJECTS//NAMED ENTITY RECOGNITION//XLXURLTXT'
    name_of_file = storetxt   # input("Enter the FileName : ")
    outFile = os.path.join(path, name_of_file + ".txt")
    with io.open(outFile,"w", encoding="utf-8") as textFile:
        textFile.write(output)
print ("DONE")
#print('output'.join(soup.stripped_strings))
```